# Support of custom backends in libgit2sharp bindings

Tags: libgit2sharp

Does libgit2sharp support custom backend configuration (similar to https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2-backends)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, libgit2 exposes the concepts of pluggable backends: There are 3 of them: object database, reference database and configuration storage.

From the LibGit2sharp latest release (v0.21) standpoint:

- The object database backend is already available through LibGit2Sharp. You can find a sample implementation at https://github.com/nulltoken/libgit2sharp.voron
- The reference database isn't done yet. There's an ongoing PR (**[#401](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/401)**) to work on this, but it's *very* outdated.
- Nothing exist yet regarding the configuration storage from the LibGit2Sharp standpoint.

This is discussed further in an open LibGit2Sharp feature request (**[Add In-Memory Repository Support](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/900)**).

Comment: Thanks. In your experience, how easy it would be to plugin something like Cassandra or other K-V store?

Comment: The Voron based implementation comes with tests that enforce the behavior the custom OdbBackend behaves as expected. The same tests are run against a file based .git repository and against a Voron based one.  If you can make your own implementation pass against those tests, you should be safe. Those tests actually provides you with a safety net regarding what is expected to happen when plugging in you own custom backend.

Comment: Regarding the ease of plugging the underlying technology, well... it depends a bit on the technology. For instance, Voron wasn't so hard to plug. @synhershko also worked on using ElasticSearch as an odb backend (see https://github.com/synhershko/libgit2sharp.Elasticsearch) and didn't seem to suffer much.

Comment: Great. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @msingh If this answer was useful to you, maybe would you consider accepting/upvoting it? ;-)

Comment: I did that to the answer. Doing the same to your comment :) . Cheers!

Comment: @nulltoken What's the current status on this after 2.5 years? We're looking at writing some custom backends using Azure's Cosmos DB and it would be great to know if the interfaces are complete so that we can write plug-in providers for each of the three backends.